# How to make a third line dock with the first bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have the following bootstrap layout:

```
<div class = "col-sm-3" id = "teste1">
</ div>

<div class = "col-sm-12" id = "teste2">
</ div>

<div class = "col-sm-9" id = "teste3">
</ div>
```

This way you will create 3 lines. I would like to know if it is possible
make the column with id "teste2" create a new line for it and the column with id "teste3" completes the first column with id "teste1". However, I need it to be in that column order, without changing to this form, as follows:

```
<div class = "col-sm-3" id = "teste1">
</ div>
<div class = "col-sm-9" id = "teste3">
</ div>
<div class = "col-sm-12" id = "teste2">
</ div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve reordering of content on different screen sizes by using [order css classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#order-classes) . For your example, like this:

```
<div class="row">
<div class = "col-sm-3 order-sm-1" id = "teste1">
  Teste 1
</div>
  <div class = "col-sm-12 order-sm-3" id = "teste2">
    Teste 2
  </div>

  <div class = "col-sm-9 order-sm-2" id = "teste3">
    Teste 3
  </div>
</div>
```